# How to make Echarts areaStyle fill whole polar?

Tags: echarts

I'm working with line-polar eCharts on Angular, and I ran into a problem with areaStyle. I want it to fill the whole area from the line to the outer most circle with the yellow color, but eCharts left out a little bit of empty space. I tried creating a shadowBlur and offsetX, Y it to the blank area, but the color is not the same. Is there a property of areaStyle I'm missing, or is there a library to fix this?

[image]

```
series = [{
        coordinateSystem: 'polar',
        name: this.legends[1],
        type: 'line',
        color: '#D9B100',
        data: this.datasetCylinder.data,
        smooth: true,
        showSymbol: false,
        lineStyle: {
          show: true,
          width: 3,
          shadowBlur: 10,
          shadowColor: 'gold'
        },
        areaStyle: {
          color: 'gold',
          origin: 'end',
          opacity: 0.1
        }
      }]
```

A simple solution would be to add more points in between, but then chart yellow line might not have the correct form. Any  suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution but you can try to find it:

1. Draw the area outside the circle boundaries and then cut the excess with VisualMap.
2. Cut area in already filled circle by VisualMap [with pieces](https://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=x2R6jHnz7I).
3. Use [custom series](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-custom) and draw all with polygons.